# What is the simplest way to validate list of string is alphanumeric only in java

Tags: java, regex, string, list

I know to validate a String is alphanumeric in Java is

```
String s1="adA12";
s1. matches("[a-zA-Z0-9]+");
```

But how to validate a List is alphanumeric the simplest way other than to iterate all element in list? I use Java 8 and Spring boot 1.x . Thank you!

Comment: Iterating all the elements *is* the simplest (and only) way to do it. You can do it with streams, but it will still be a loop over the list.

Comment: FYI, that regex will match "????adA12_111__" as well. Is that what you want?

Comment: How about good, old, trusted, tested, NPE-proof Apache [`StringUtils.isAlphanumeric()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isAlphanumeric-java.lang.CharSequence-)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Predicate<String> alphaNumericFilter = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9]+").asPredicate();

Boolean isListAlphaNumeric = list.stream().allMatch(alphaNumericFilter);
```

I think this is the easiest and simplest way.

Comment: Oh nice, I didn't know about the `asPredicate()` method. This can come in handy, thank you! (But this answer is missing an essential part of the question: »how to validate a List is alphanumeric«)

Comment: Here is that thing I just missed, 
Boolean isListAlphaNumric = list.stream().allMatch(alphaNumaricFilter);

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, you have no choice but going over all the elements of the list and check them one by one (or at least all the elements until you fail a check). Java 8 does offer some syntactic sugar to make this neater, though:

```java
boolean allAlphaNumeric = myList.stream().allMatch(s -> s.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9]+"));
```

Comment: that will (re)compile the regex for every item in the list...

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate your string collection *somehow* (excluding any inefficient hacks of joining all strings before and then testing the full string – but, behind the scenes this is iterating the collection too!)

But one valid approach would probably be to use streams:

```java
// pre-compiling the pattern avoids having the runtime parse the
// regex for every single item in your collection, which can become slow
private static final Pattern VALID_PATTERN
    = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$"); // ^ and $ anchors to prevent from having other characters

private static boolean validate(final String s) {
    return VALID_PATTERN.matcher(s).matches();
}

// later, in your logic:
void yourBusinessLogic() {
    final List<String> strings = List.of("abc", "123", "some_thing");
    final boolean allValid = strings.stream()
            .allMatch(YourClass::validate);
}
```

Comment: Or, as I just learned, with Java 11+: `strings.stream().allMatch(VALID_PATTERN.asMatchPredicate())`

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest and fastest way would be to join all items into one String and then all you need is one time check for alphanumeric:

```
List<String> strs = ...
boolean isAllAlphanumeric = StringUtils.isAlphanumeric(String.join("", strs));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Vavr](https://www.vavr.io/), you can do the following which is rather slim:

```
private List<String> filterInvalidAlphaNumericValues(List<String> values) {
    Predicate<String> alphaNumericFilter = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z\\d\\-\\_]+").asPredicate();
    return values.filter(alphaNumericFilter);
}
```